# Datatables - Inline editor only updates host table

Tags: datatables

I have a simple table using a left join:

```
Editor::inst( $db, 'enqitem', 'enqitemid')
->fields(
    Field::inst( 'salstkitem.salsubid' ),
    Field::inst( 'salstkitem.condition1' ),
    Field::inst( 'enqitem.cost' )         
)
->leftJoin('salstkitem', 'salstkitem.salsubid', '=', 'enqitem.itemid')
->where('enqitem.enqnr',141316)
->debug( true )
->process( $_POST )
->json();
```

In the editor, I have hidden the primary key of the non-host table:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: "datatables.php",
    table: "#example",
    fields: [{
            name: "salstkitem.salsubid",
            type: "hidden"
         },{
            label: "Condition:",
            name: "salstkitem.condition1"
        },{
            label: "Cost:",
            name: "enqitem.cost"
        }
    ]
});
```

I've set it to be editable inline:

```
$('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
    editor.inline( this, {
        onBlur: 'submit'
    } );
});
```

When I edit inline, the cost updates successfully, as it's a member of the host table. However condition1 will not update.
If I select the EDIT button, both fields update successfully.

This issue is purely for inline editing.

Does anyone have any idea why?
The debug suggests it isn't trying to update at all. It is purely a SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

Allan, the creator of datatables got back to me:

If you are writing to a joined table rather than just the master table you need to have Editor submit the joined table's primary key as well (enqitem.enqitemid in this case I guess). When you are inline editing, by default it will only submit the edited field, but you can use the form-options object to change that:

```
editor.inline( this, {
    onBlur: 'submit',
    submit: 'allIfChanged'
} );
```

Regards,
Allan